# Error for open connect of database with FMDB

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, sqlite, touch, fmdb

When I'm going to open connect with database, console says: "error opening!: 14".
I included "mybase.sqlite" on folder Resources of my project and I'm using the FMDB framework.

For open connect I'm using this code:

```
 NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];    
    FMDatabase* db = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:@"/mybase.sqlite"];
    if (![db open]) {
        NSLog(@"Não abriu o banco de dados.");
        [pool release];
        return 0;
    }
```

In AppDelegate, I included this code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary
*)launchOptions {    

    // Override point for customization after application launch.  HomeViewController *homeVC = [[HomeViewController alloc] init];  navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:homeVC];    [self createEditableCopyOfDatabaseIfNeeded];  [window addSubview:navigationController.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible]; 
    return YES; }

- (void)createEditableCopyOfDatabaseIfNeeded{  BOOL success;  NSFileManager
*fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];  NSError *error;  NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);  NSString
*documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];  NSString
*writableDBPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"mybase.sqlite"];  success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:writableDBPath];  NSLog(@"Success %d", success);  if (success) return;    NSString
*defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"mybase.sqlite"];  success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath toPath:writableDBPath error:&error];  if (!success) {   NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to create writable database file with message '%@'.", [error localizedDescription]);  }  }
```

Comment: Lucas you should mark the answer as accepted, as it answered your question.

Comment: @LucasMoreria This still wasn't accepted? It's a perfect answer.

Comment: @slycrel's answer is perfect and it's working. you should mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: My mistake! I was new here. Sorry for that. His answer is indeed excelent.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think your open path is likely incorrect.  You are specifying a path that doesn't make sense, as if your DB file was in the root folder.

```
FMDatabase* db = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:@"/mybase.sqlite"];
```

The above should use this code for the file path, which you already have in the question.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; 
NSString *writableDBPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"mybase.sqlite"];
FMDatabase* db = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:writableDBPath];
```

Comment: It's works, but the first line isn't correct. It's work just like this:

 NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

Comment: doh, copy paste error on my part from the original description.  Thanks!